# Unable to load a file at WEB-INF location

Tags: java, maven, file, classloader

There is a json file in my war in the following location

```
   WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/jsonFolder/file.json
```

I am trying to access file using the path and following method to load my file.

```
public static File deserializeJSONFile() throws IOException {
    File file = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
String jsonPath = "jsonFolder/file.json";
try (InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(jsonPath)) {
        in = inputStream;
        if (in != null) {
            byte[] bufferArray = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(bufferArray);
            file = new File("tempJsonFile.json");
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outStream.write(bufferArray);
        }
    } finally {
        if (outStream != null) {
            outStream.close();
        }
    }
    if (null == in) {
        String errorMessage = "JSON file: " + jsonPath + " could not be loaded";
        FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException = new FileNotFoundException(errorMessage);
        logger.error(errorMessage, fileNotFoundException);
        throw fileNotFoundException;
    }
    return file ;
  }
```

with which all my unit tests pass. On deployment of my app, I see the file not found exception for jsonFolder/file.json. When I traced the actual location as where it is searching, it is looking at,

```
 C:\Program Files\eclipse-mars\jsonFolder\file.json
```

which is incorrect. I tried different classloader methods but it did not help. One rule is I should not modify pom.xml to make this work. How can I load the file?

Comment: Can you show us the proper code? This code doesn't compile, given that it's missing `"`s and `;`s.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: This is still not valid: `String jsonPath = jsonFolder/file.json`

Comment: correction complete

Comment: Stack trace please, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a json file in my war in the following location

WEB-INF->classes->META-INF->jsonFolder->file.json

So its name as a resource is `META-INF/jsonFolder/file.json`. Not what you have in your code.

Comment: As I said it works fine in my unit tests as it is available in my target folder. When I package to a war and deploy it to tomcat, thats when I see this error.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  JSON file: jsonFolder/file.json could not be loaded
 at ....NegotiationUtil.deserializeJsonFile(NegotiationUtil.java:71)
 at ....ResourceManager.<init>(ResourceManager.java:128)

here the deserializeJsonFile() is the implementation that is shown above in the try block.

Comment: So you threw this exception yourself? Can't see that in the code. Hard to help when you don't provide all the relevant information.

Comment: I see what you saying, please see the edited info with exception thrown. I am sorry that I missed it. When I tried to trace the location as where the classloader actualy looks for, I see it point to C:\Program Files\eclipse-mars\jsonFolder\file.json instead of location in the war.